# Rails lower case field input for login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, input, authentication

In rails in my database I have a user called  me@gmail.com  but if I attempt to login with ME@gmail.com. I can't. Clearly my field is not becoming lower cased before it attempts to login. I know I should do a...

`before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }`

But from what I understand that goes in the model. But I only have a sessions controller. Not a sessions model. So how should I achieve the same effect?

**my current user model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :name

  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password
  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save { |user| user.name = name.downcase }
  before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }
  before_create { generate_token(:email_token) }
```

**my current sessions controller**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
      if user
        if user.email_activation_token == true
          if params[:remember_me]
            cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
          else
            cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
          end
          redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
        else
          flash.now.alert = "You email has not yet been verified. Please click the link in your email." 
          render "new"
        end
      else
        flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
        render "new"
      end
  end
```

**the form field in question**

```
= form_tag sessions_path do
  %p
    = label_tag :email
    = text_field_tag :email, params[:email]
  %p
    = label_tag :password
    = password_field_tag :password
  %p.button
    %input{name: "commit", type: "submit", value: "Log in"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
user = User.authenticate(params[:email].downcase, params[:password])
```

OR

In method `authenticate` smth like this:

```
User.where("LOWER(email) = LOWER(?)", email).first
```

Comment: Worked like a charm sir. Your a gentlemen and a scholar!